# Why can I convert from int ** to int * in the case of the two-dimensional array, but not in the case of the array of pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, casting, int

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
    int arr2d[3][3] = { {1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9} };
    int* arr = (int*)arr2d;
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }

    printf("\n\n");
    int arr1[] = { 11,12 };
    int arr2[] = {13, 14, 15, 16};
    int arr3[] = { 17, 18, 19 };
    int * parr[3] = { arr1,arr2,arr3 };
    int *parr1 = (int*)parr;
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", parr1[i]);
    }
    return 0;
```

here at the start i converted from   two-dimensional array and printed it but after that i did it with array of pointer and it didn't work can someone please explain it?

Comment: post the code not link. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: [This *link* might help](https://www.google.com/search?q=trolled+meme&safe=off&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjXkp7ngsvaAhUDs48KHTuUDEYQ_AUICigB&biw=1366&bih=637#imgrc=E8xkZn5biKaAVM:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to learn how these objects are laid out in memory:

```
int array[][3] = { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9} };
int *p_array = (int *) array;
```

This creates an object `array` of type `int[][3]` in memory (in this case stack) physically laid out in a hypothetical (16-bit word size) architecture as:

```
  array 0x8000: 0x0001
        0x8002: 0x0002
        0x8004: 0x0003
        0x8006: 0x0004
        0x8008: 0x0005
        0x800A: 0x0006
        0x800C: 0x0007
        0x800E: 0x0008
        0x8010: 0x0009
p_array 0x8012: 0x8000
```

Where `0x8000` denotes the imaginary stack address of `array`.

However, in your second example:

```
int array1[] = { 11, 12 };
int array2[] = { 13, 14, 15, 16 };
int array3[] = { 17, 18, 19 };
int *array_pointers[] = { array1, array2, array3 };

int *array_pointers2 = (int*) array_pointers;
```

Here `array_pointers` is of type `int *[]` which means it is a pointer to array of `int`s. And the memory layout would be like the following:

```
array1 0x8000: 0x000B
       0x8002: 0x000C
array2 0x8004: 0x000D
       0x8006: 0x000E
       0x8008: 0x000F
       0x800A: 0x0010
array3 0x800C: 0x0011
       0x800E: 0x0012
       0x8010: 0x0013
```

and

```
array_pointers:  0x8012: 0x8000 address of array1
                 0x8014: 0x8004 address of array2
                 0x8016: 0x800C address of array3
array_pointers2: 0x8018: 0x8012 address of array_pointers
```

So when you try to print the contents of `array_pointers2`, which now contain pointers to array of `int`s, you will print the address values rather than the numbers they point to.

Here is an example that outputs the memory address of those objects:

https://ideone.com/T52Ow0

Which prints:

```
array      0x7ffeda682090: 0x00000000000001
           0x7ffeda682094: 0x00000000000002
           0x7ffeda682098: 0x00000000000003
           0x7ffeda68209c: 0x00000000000004
           0x7ffeda6820a0: 0x00000000000005
           0x7ffeda6820a4: 0x00000000000006
           0x7ffeda6820a8: 0x00000000000007
           0x7ffeda6820ac: 0x00000000000008
           0x7ffeda6820b0: 0x00000000000009
p_array    0x7ffeda682038: 0x007ffeda682090

array1     0x7ffeda68204c: 0x0000000000000b
           0x7ffeda682050: 0x0000000000000c
array2     0x7ffeda682060: 0x0000000000000d
           0x7ffeda682064: 0x0000000000000e
           0x7ffeda682068: 0x0000000000000f
           0x7ffeda68206c: 0x00000000000010
array3     0x7ffeda682054: 0x00000000000011
           0x7ffeda682058: 0x00000000000012
           0x7ffeda68205c: 0x00000000000013
array_poin 0x7ffeda682070: 0x007ffeda68204c
           0x7ffeda682078: 0x007ffeda682060
           0x7ffeda682080: 0x007ffeda682054
array_poi2 0x7ffeda682040: 0x007ffeda682070
```

on my computer.

Source code for that in case external link expires:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int array[][3] = { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9} };
    int *p_array = (int*) array;

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        printf("%-10s %08p: %016p\n", i == 0 ? "array" : "", &p_array[i], p_array[i]);
    }

    printf("%-10s %08p: %016p\n", "p_array", &p_array, p_array);

    int array1[] = { 11, 12 };
    int array2[] = { 13, 14, 15, 16 };
    int array3[] = { 17, 18, 19 };

    int *array_pointers[] = { array1, array2, array3 };
    int *array_pointers2 = (int*) array_pointers;

    putchar('\n');

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(array1) / sizeof(array1[0]); i++) {
        printf("%-10s %08p: %016p\n", i == 0 ? "array1" : "", &array1[i], array1[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(array2) / sizeof(array2[0]); i++) {
        printf("%-10s %08p: %016p\n", i == 0 ? "array2" : "", &array2[i], array2[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(array3) / sizeof(array3[0]); i++) {
        printf("%-10s %08p: %016p\n", i == 0 ? "array3" : "", &array3[i], array3[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(array_pointers) / sizeof(array_pointers[0]); i++) {
        printf("%-10s %08p: %016p\n", i == 0 ? "array_poin" : "", &array_pointers[i], array_pointers[i]);
    }

    printf("%-10s %08p: %016p\n", "array_poi2", &array_pointers2, array_pointers2);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply use `int *` with a single loop from 0 to N as you would with contiguous arrays of integers like `arr2d` since:

1. the pointers may be far apart in memory
2. you need to dereference each of those pointers, which you can't do with `int *` since `int *` will interpret `A[i]` as an `int`, not a pointer.

To understand how to fix it, you might want to understand how things are laid out in memory.  Let's start with an easy one: your `arr2d` declaration.  Assuming a 2-byte `int`, here's how it might look:

```
arr2d @ 0x8000
 =======================
|  arr2d[0] @ 0x8000    |
|   -----------------   |
|  | 1      2      3 |  |
|   -----------------   |
|  @8000  @8002  @8004  |
|                       |
|  arr2d[1] @ 0x8006    |
|   -----------------   |
|  | 4      5      6 |  |
|   -----------------   |
|  @8006  @8008  @800A  |
|                       |
|  arr2d[0] @ 0x800C    |
|   -----------------   |
|  | 7      8      9 |  |
|   -----------------   |
|  @800C  @800E  @8010  |
 =======================
```

Notice how the memory addresses from one item to the next are all 2 bytes apart?  This is one reason why you can do `int* arr = (int*)arr2d` and print `arr[i]` to get the values you want.  The other reason is the fact that you're storing integers.

Now let's look at `parr` and `arr1`, `arr2`, and `arr3`:

```
arr1 @ 0xA000
 ----------
| 11    12 |
 ----------
@A000  @A002

arr2 @ 0xB000
 -------------------------
| 13     14     15     16 |
 -------------------------
@B000  @B002  @B004  @B006

arr3 @ 0xC000
 ------------------
| 17     18     19 |
 ------------------
@C000  @C002  @C004

parr @ 0xE000
 ------------------------
| @A000   @B000   @C000  |
| (arr1)  (arr2)  (arr3) |
 ------------------------
  @E000   @E004   @E008
```

Remember what I said about `arr2d` storing integers?  Well, `parr` stores pointers, so things work a bit differently.  For one thing, you need to dereference a pointer using the `*` operator, but you're using `int *parr1`, so `parr1[i]` results in a pointer being interpreted incorrectly as an integer.  Also notice the addresses of the integers increase by 2 in each array while the addresses of the pointers (@E000..@E008) increase by 4.  In other words, you're interpreting a 4-byte pointer as a 2-byte integer, which can make your problem worse if your system is using different sizes for `int` and `int *`.  If you declare `int **parr1 = parr` instead and use `*parr1[i]` for printing, things will be much better.

However, this will only print the first value in each array.  That's because you're storing pointers to the first item in each array (because **array decay** turns `arr1` into `&arr1[0]`, `arr2` into `&arr2[0]`, and `arr3` into `&arr3[0]`).  Pointers have no element count because they're not arrays, and since you're storing a pointer to a single `int` rather than a pointer to an array, you're effectively removing the element count anyway.  You'd need to keep track of the element count of each array yourself, perhaps in another array.  Here's some modified code that fixes your problem:

```
// Only works for real arrays, not pointers returned by malloc/calloc.
#define ARRAY_COUNT(a) (sizeof (a) / sizeof (a)[0])
int arr1[] = { 11,12 };
int arr2[] = {13, 14, 15, 16};
int arr3[] = { 17, 18, 19 };
int * parr[3] = { arr1,arr2,arr3 };
int **parr1 = (int*)parr;
int counts[] = { ARRAY_COUNT(arr1), ARRAY_COUNT(arr2), ARRAY_COUNT(arr3) };
for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_COUNT(counts); i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < counts[i]; j++)
    {
        printf("%d ", parr1[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Note that I used two loops: 1 for the counts and 1 for each array's content. If you really wanted, you could merge the two loops, but it's a bit more difficult to follow the logic:

```
i = 0;
j = 0;
while (i < ARRAY_COUNT(counts))
{
    if (j < counts[i]) {
        printf("%d ", parr1[i][j]);
        j++;
    } else {
        i++;
        j = 0;
    }
}
```